# Separate SSL Certs on Regular and Mobile Subdomain

Tags: ssl, vps

I have a SSL cert installed on http://example.com. I've finished a mobile version of the same site and it sits on http://mobile.example.com. I need to secure that subdomain as well so I purchased another SSL. But now I'm trying to understand how to set it up.. because I know you can only have one SSL per server, correct?

So what's the correct way to go about this? Do I need to change the original SSL to wildcard? Do I need two SSLs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a wildcard certificate or a certificate that allows multiple SANs (Subject Alt Names).  How you set them up is very dependent on your web server. A wildcard certificate only works for subdomains, while SANs can be used for completely unrelated domains.

With Apache (don't know about others) you can also use two separate certificates as long as you're willing to drop support for XP-users (see e.g. http://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/apache-multiple-ssl-certificates-using-sni.htm for details).